# How to pull image out of container with position absolute but keep in document flow?

Tags: html, css

I have a content container that is 500px wide and floated to the right. This container contains text and then an image and then some more text. Ultimately I would like to pull this image out of the bounding 500px container and have it span the full width of the page, which for argument sake is 1000px wide. In effect the images will be full-width (1000px wide) while the content container is only 500px wide. What is the best way to do something like this so that the image can be at full width?

[jsfiddle.net/QCb3R/](http://jsfiddle.net/QCb3R/)

I would like to pull the image to extend fully outside of the .content div.

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="content">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam id dapibus mauris. Curabitur lectus metus, tincidunt sit amet varius et, euismod et neque. Sed a odio odio. Morbi placerat condimentum fermentum. Nam eleifend congue malesuada. Vivamus vel lorem eu leo blandit placerat. Nunc turpis justo, iaculis vestibulum interdum sit amet, luctus nec dui. Duis ultrices eleifend sem eget mattis. Quisque at purus nisi. Duis porta porttitor nisi nec ornare. Nam eu dolor urna, a suscipit libero. Morbi risus dui, egestas eget consectetur quis, malesuada vitae orci. Maecenas pulvinar malesuada elit eget sagittis. Curabitur congue, mauris quis pretium ultricies, augue nisl dapibus libero, eu lacinia sem nunc commodo purus. Quisque tellus purus, sodales a consequat in, adipiscing in odio. Donec non felis at felis sodales varius vitae non lorem.</p>

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/" />

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam id dapibus mauris. Curabitur lectus metus, tincidunt sit amet varius et, euismod et neque. Sed a odio odio. Morbi placerat condimentum fermentum. Nam eleifend congue malesuada. Vivamus vel lorem eu leo blandit placerat. Nunc turpis justo, iaculis vestibulum interdum sit amet, luctus nec dui. Duis ultrices eleifend sem eget mattis. Quisque at purus nisi. Duis porta porttitor nisi nec ornare. Nam eu dolor urna, a suscipit libero. Morbi risus dui, egestas eget consectetur quis, malesuada vitae orci. Maecenas pulvinar malesuada elit eget sagittis. Curabitur congue, mauris quis pretium ultricies, augue nisl dapibus libero, eu lacinia sem nunc commodo purus. Quisque tellus purus, sodales a consequat in, adipiscing in odio. Donec non felis at felis sodales varius vitae non lorem.</p>

  </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.content {
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Show us what your HTML/CSS looks like now. Or even better, make a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I updated the question with a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: And you want to maintain the regular flow of your `500px` container div? The short answer here is, you can't. Using `position: absolute` by definition removes it from the document flow. What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps there is another approach. Are you stuck with this html or can that change? Why does the image have to be in this `500px` div?

Comment: The image has to be in the 500px as this is the content area that content is injected into from WordPress CMS. Text and images are inputted in the WordPress WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy to create that effect, but not by setting the image to be absolutely positioned.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QCb3R/2/)

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
p {
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
}
.content {
    width: 1000px;
    float: right;
}
```

The problem with setting the image to be absolutely positioned is exactly because it takes the image out of the normal document flow. You would have to fill up the gap left by the original image with a place holder element of the same height, and then position the absolutely positioned image over the top of the place holder element. That sounds like a job for JavaScript as it would require access to the DOM to retrieve the position of elements on the page, that can't be done with CSS and HTML only.